# what is the appropriate lucene analyzer to use?

Tags: java, lucene, standardanalyzer

i have problems with regards to indexing item names with numbers and symbols. a sample of my data is shown below:

```
ANGLE BARS   ORANGE - 4.0MM 2 - 1/2"
B.I SQUARE TUBING     2" X 3"
B.I. PIPE S-40   10MM 3/8"
B.I SQUARE TUBING     1" X 2"
PLYWOOD   MARINE 3/4X4X8
PLYWOOD   STA. CLARA 1/8X4X8
PLYWOOD   STA. CLARA 3/16X4X8
```

i want to tokenize my data in white or trailing spaces without dropping the symbols because these symbols are very essential. so that whenever i search for "plywood sta. clara", "b.i square 2" X 3"", or "angle orange 2 - 1/2" will give me a result. i tried to used whitespace analyzer but the symbols are dropped. i also tried standardanalyzer but stop words and symbols are also dropped. what is the best analyzer to use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PatternAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/contrib-memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/PatternAnalyzer.html) by writing regular expression or create [Custom Analyzer.](http://www.jillesvangurp.com/2008/05/31/lucene-custom-analyzer/)

Comment: will i also use PatternAnalyzer when searching?

Comment: Yes.You should use same analyzer while indexing and searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.PatternAnalyzer.  You can supply a regular expression to define token delimiters.